# NSInteger staying null after getting value from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, row

What I want to do is getting an NSInteger from another class with a method and then use the value I got in an IBAction.

So in my .h file I have:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger row;
-(void) selectedRow : (NSInteger) selectedRow;
-(IBAction)changeName:(id)sender;
```

And in my .m file:

```
@synthesize row;

-(void) selectedRow : (NSInteger) selectedRow {

    row = selectedRow; //I tried also self.row

}

-(IBAction)changeName:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"row = %lu", (long)row); //To keep it simple.
```

When I debug at row, it tells me, that row got the value of the other class, but in the IBAction it's 0.

Can please someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is `selectedRow` called? I'm guessing you have multiple instances of this class, and selectedRow is called for one, and you are calling `changeName` for some other instance.

Comment: I called it in the other class to get the indexPath.row of an tableView. I thought, row would get the value of selectedRow in all the methods.

Comment: Well it doesn't. You can call the `[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`of the tableview to get the currently selected row.

Comment: Instead of declaring row as property (nonatomic) NSInteger row , try changing it to property (class) NSInteger row and remove synthesize row in .m file. Guess this should work without using NSUserDefaults!

Comment: I did, in the other class. But I needed the value of row in this class.

Comment: @VamshiKrishna OK, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
-(void) selectedRow : (NSInteger) selectedRow {

    //row = selectedRow; //I tried also self.row
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"Row"];
}

-(IBAction)changeName:(id)sender {

    NSInteger selectedRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Row"];
    NSLog(@"row = %ld",(long)selectedRow); //To keep it simple.
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
func selectedRow(selectedRow:Int) -> Void {

    UserDefaults.standard .set(selectedRow, forKey: "Row")
}

@IBAction func changeName(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let selectedRow = UserDefaults.standard .integer(forKey: "Row")
    print("row = \(selectedRow)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now I need to check for what NSUserDefaults is used for.